# Mock a function in a class in closure javascript jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock a single function in a class declared inside a closure.

```js
const CacheManager = (function() {
  class _CacheManager {
    constructor() {
      return this;
    }

    public async readAsPromise(topic, filter, cacheType = 'CORE') {
      if (topic.toLowerCase().equals(TOPICS[TT])) {
        const data = new Array();
        data.push(getData());
        return data;
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  let instance;
  return {
    getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new _CacheManager();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  };
})();

export { CacheManager };
```

I call the readAsPromise method from another class as shown below

```js
    class A {
     async read(param1, param2) {    
          let array = await CacheManager.getInstance().readAsPromise('topic')      
          return array[0]    
      }
    }
```

I call the read method from my test as shown below

```js
    A a = new A();
    a.read(param1, param2).then(....)
```

In the above code, I want to mock the method readAsPromise. When I tried to mock the module using genMockFromModule as below:

```
const utils = jest.genMockFromModule('cache/cache_manager').CacheManager;
```

It has only the getInstance method so I won't be able to mock readAsPromise method. Can someone throw some light on how I can mock readAsPromise method inside the class _CacheManager. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Update: I have added the complete details of the flow of control to make my question clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
const TOPICS = [];
const TT = '';

interface ICacheManager {
  readAsPromise(topic, filter, cacheType?): any;
  someMethod(name: string, filter): any;
}

const CacheManager = (function cacheManager() {
  class _CacheManager implements ICacheManager {
    constructor() {
      return this;
    }

    public async readAsPromise(topic, filter, cacheType = 'CORE') {
      if (topic.toLowerCase().equals(TOPICS[TT])) {
        const data = new Array();
        data.push(this.getData());
        return data;
      }
      return null;
    }

    public async someMethod(name: string, filter) {
      console.log(name, filter);
      const data = await this.readAsPromise(name, filter);
      if (data) {
        return data;
      }
      throw new Error('no data');
    }

    private getData() {
      return '';
    }
  }

  let instance;
  return {
    getInstance(): ICacheManager {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = new _CacheManager();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  };
})();

export { CacheManager };
```

`someMethod` invoke `readAsPromise` method in order to demonstrating how to mock `readAsPromise` method

Unit tests:

```js
import { CacheManager } from './';

const cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();

cacheManager.readAsPromise = jest.fn();

describe('CacheManager', () => {
  describe('#someMethod', () => {
    it('should throw error', async () => {
      (cacheManager.readAsPromise as jest.Mock<any>).mockReturnValueOnce('java');
      const actualValue = await cacheManager.someMethod('jest', 'where');
      expect(actualValue).toBe('java');
      expect(cacheManager.readAsPromise).toBeCalledWith('jest', 'where');
    });
  });
});
```

test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/mock-closure/index.spec.ts
  CacheManager
    #someMethod
      ✓ should throw error (27ms)

  console.log src/mock-closure/index.ts:25
    jest where

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.671s, estimated 2s
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I think I was not clear. I am not calling the readAsPromise function within my test. I call method read() of another class from my test and it in turn calls readAsPromise. I need to call my mock when the method is called from this file. I have updated the question with the details